# derive one css property from another

Tags: css

Can I have something like below in my .scss file?

```
.class{
        width: 300px;
        .class2{
                width: inherit;
                min-width: calc(width - 10%);
        }
}
```

Comment: if you are removing 10% for the width then the min-width is useless because X - 10% is always smaller than X

Answer (score 0):

First, `width:inherit` will inherit the value ONLY from the direct parent.

This will work for something like this:

```html
<div class="class">
  <div class="class2">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

But not for something like this:

```html
<div class="class">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="class2">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I suggest using a CSS variable. Here's my take on what I think you're trying to achieve (otherwise, it doesn't make much sense to me...):

```scss
.class{
  --class-width: 300px;
  width: var(--class-width);

  .class2{
    width: calc(var(--class-width) - 10%);
  }
}
```

Here is the MDN documentation for CSS vars:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties